# Factor of Dataframe (R) not changing to POSIXct

Tags: r, dataframe, posixct

The data frame (R) Look like:

```
str(v2)
'data.frame':   160 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ TimeStamp: Factor w/ 104 levels "2015-04-01 09:00:00",..: 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ Bid      : num  2515 2554 2554 2515 2520 ...
 $ Bid_Sze  : int  1 133 168 1 5 3 10 5 12 12 ...
 $ Ask      : num  2594 2565 2594 2570 2560 ...
 $ Ask_Sze  : int  5 1 5 10 5 15 150 22 148 98 ...
```

When changing timestamp to POSIXct, Console is showing as

> v2$Timestamp<-as.POSIXct(v2$Timestamp, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S)
>   +

After + the program is not moving. Please help how this factor can be changed to POSIXct as it to required to force this data frame to xts.

Comment: First, you need to change `Timestamp`to character first.  And you probably need to press `ESC` before you enter this line

Comment: Dear, it's not working evenif by changing Timestamp to chacter first 'data.frame': 160 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ TimeStamp: chr  "2015-04-01 09:00:00" "2015-04-01 09:00:04" "2015-04-01 09:00:04" "2015-04-01 09:00:06" ...
 $ Bid      : num  2515 2554 2554 2515 2520 ...
 $ Bid_Sze  : int  1 133 168 1 5 3 10 5 12 12 ...
 $ Ask      : num  2594 2565 2594 2570 2560 ...
 $ Ask_Sze  : int  5 1 5 10 5 15 150 22 148 98 ...